# Testing war file using TestNG

Tags: testing, jar, testng, war

I have just created a web service in eclipse and exported as war file like ***myService.war***.Can i make a separate testing tool as jar file which tests ***myService.war*** file.
I want to use testNG api by which whenever i run that jar file,it tests myService.war .

Answer (score 0):

[Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/) will be your best friend for testing war. And [it supports TestNG](http://arquillian.org/modules/core-platform/) out of box.